# Change mousewheel zooming on ZedGraph controls

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

So I have a few `zedGraphControls` on a `tabPage` that got a scrollBar. When I scroll my mouse wheel on a `zedGraphControl`, it both (un)zoom the zedGraph pane and the `tabPage`. Kind of annoying.

Is it possible to add a modifier key to the *zoom with wheel* feature, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Comment: Do you mean that it *scrolls* the tab page at the same time it zooms the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZedGraphControl_MouseWheel` event handler inside the `ZedGraphControl` is protected, so you can't inherit it as a usercontrol and override this event. Though I suspect if you wanted to compile with ZedGraphControl source code you could change this.

One option is to disable the tab page from listening to the mouse wheel scroll event, as discussed here: [Make tabpage not process mousewheel events (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351046/make-tabpage-not-process-mousewheel-events-c)

Alternatively you can disable the ZedGraphControl zoom-on-mousewheel behavior by setting this property:

```
zedGraphControl1.IsEnableWheelZoom = false;
```